# WPF: DataGridColumn loses DataContext when trying to bind a property to IsReadOnly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am trying to set `IsReadOnly` in a `DataGridTextColumn` by binding it to a property. Sounds simple.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsLocked}" />
```

The main binding to the Name property of my ViewModel works fine. But the binding in IsReadOnly fails because the DataContext is `null`. But why?
Name and IsLocked are on the same level in my ViewModel, and a few lines later IsLocked is used to display an icon by toggling visibility.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsLocked}" />

    <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn
        Header="Produktart" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsLocked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsEditable="True"
        Width="100"
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
        ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ProducerTypesValues, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
                
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="In Benutzung" IsReadOnly="true">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Lock" x:Name="lockIcon" Visibility="{Binding IsLocked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter }}" />
                    </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

What can I do to set the binding in IsReadOnly correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why?

Because the `DataGridTextColumn` is not part of the visual tree and doesn't inherit any `DataContext`.

The solution to get this working is to use a `Freezable` that captures the `DataContext` as explained and exemplified [here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

Comment: That's it, thank you. I still don't really understand the underlying basics, but at least it works.